# Convert the list output to create a data.frame in dplyr pipe

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyr

I am extracting patterns with a regex and building a data.frame with dplyr

```
library (dplyr)
library (stringr)

Target <- c("@user1 lorem ipsum @user2", "@user3 lorem ipsum @user4")
Source <-  c(" lorem ipsum", "dolores")
dataset <- data.frame(Source, Target)


dataset2 <- dataset %>%
mutate (Target=str_extract_all(v1, "@\\w+"))
```

My results (data.frame):

```
lorem ipsum c("@user1", "@user2")
dolores     c("@user3", "@user4")
```

What I want in a *data.frame* object:

```
lorem ipsum  "@user1"
lorem ipsum  "@user2"
dolores      "@user3"
dolores      "@user4"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
stack(setNames(str_extract_all(dataset$Target, "@\\w+"), dataset$Source))[2:1]
#          ind values    
#1  lorem ipsum @user1
#2  lorem ipsum @user2
#3      dolores @user3
#4      dolores @user4
```

---

Or we can use `unnest` from `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dataset %>% 
      mutate(Target = str_extract_all(Target, "@\\w+")) %>%
      unnest
#        Source Target
#1  lorem ipsum @user1
#2  lorem ipsum @user2
#3      dolores @user3
#4      dolores @user4
```

Comment: It works great @akrun! So, can you help me to find a better title to my question?

Comment: @Wilcar Glad to help you.  Perhaps `Convert the list output to create a data.frame`